# How to search through a (filtered) QSortFilterProxyModel in Qt (C++)?

Tags: c++, qt, search, model, qsortfilterproxymodel

I have a working filter function (`filterAcceptsRow`) that filters a hierarchical `QTreeView` based on the first column (index0). I need to connect a search `QLineEdit` in order to let the user search trough the (filtered) `QTreeView`. I am not sure how to add a search algorithm to this function. Can anyone help me figuring out? The search algorithm should search for a `QString` in all 5 columns (index0-index4).

**My filter function:**

```
bool ProxyModel::filterAcceptsRow(int sourceRow, const QModelIndex &sourceParent) const
{
    QModelIndex index0 = sourceModel()->index(sourceRow, 0, sourceParent);
    QModelIndex index1 = sourceModel()->index(sourceRow, 1, sourceParent);
    QModelIndex index2 = sourceModel()->index(sourceRow, 2, sourceParent);
    QModelIndex index3 = sourceModel()->index(sourceRow, 3, sourceParent);
    QModelIndex index4 = sourceModel()->index(sourceRow, 4, sourceParent);

    if (m_filterEnabled)
    {
        foreach (const QString &row, rows)
        {
            if (sourceModel()->data(index0).toString().contains(row) && m_shownRow)
                return true; //element should be shown
            else if (sourceModel()->data(index0).toString().contains(row) && !m_shownRow)
                return false; //element should NOT be shown
        }
        if (m_shownRow)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    } else {
        return true; //no filter -> show everything
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to chain 2 proxymodels.

I made something similar for table, but believe that for tree it will work the same way.

You create your class derived from `QSortFilterProxyModel` and implement `filterAcceptsRow` (here example with the usage of regexp):

```
bool QubyxSearchFilterProxyModel::filterAcceptsRow(int sourceRow,const QModelIndex &sourceParent) const
{
    for(int i = 0; i < sourceModel()->columnCount(); i ++)
    {
        QModelIndex index = sourceModel()->index(sourceRow, i, sourceParent);
        if(sourceModel()->data(index).toString().toLower().trimmed().contains(filterRegExp()))
            return true;
    }

    return false;  
}
```

Regexp you can set in one of your slot which handles search lineedit changing:

```
QRegExp regExp(widget->lineEditSearch->text().toLower(),Qt::CaseSensitive,QRegExp::FixedString);
searchProxyModel_->setFilterRegExp(regExp);
```

And in the tree code:

```
searchProxyModel_->setSourceModel(model);
proxyModel_->setSourceModel(searchProxyModel_);
```